# how to list filename using find and grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I want list filename in a recursive directory based on filename pattern.

Here is the code I have developed so far:

```
find . -name "*pipeline*" | grep -R 'pipeline'
```

However its output is:

```
static/js/angular/angular-scenario.js:   * and `$validators` pipelines. If there are no special {@link ngModelOptions} specified then the staged
static/js/angular/angular-scenario.js:   * will not invoke the `$parsers` and `$validators` pipelines. For this reason, you should
static/js/angular/angular.js: * * if the value returned from the `$parsers` transformation pipeline has not changed
static/js/angular/angular.js: * @property {Array.<Function>} $parsers Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever
static/js/angular/angular.js: * @property {Array.<Function>} $formatters Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever
static/js/angular/angular.js:   * and `$validators` pipelines. If there are no special {@link ngModelOptions} specified then the staged
static/js/angular/angular.js:   * will not invoke the `$parsers` and `$validators` pipelines. For this reason, you should
social/pipeline.py:    print ("at pipeline *******", details, uid, social, kwargs, response)
```

And the result I am expecting will be a file name with **pipeline** as shown below:

```
social/pipeline.py
social/__pycache__/pipeline.cpython-35.pyc
```

Comment: What did you get? What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Please add your file tree structure and the output you wish so we can help you further

Comment: @neuromatter updated your changes

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes updated your changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## command

```
find ./ -type f -print | grep -i pipeline*
```

## output will be

```
./social/pipeline.py
./social/__pycache__/pipeline.cpython-35.pyc
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to list names of files that contain 'XYZ'. If it is so, you can do this:

```
find . -name "*pipeline*" -exec grep -l XYZ {} \;
```

What this does is it finds all files that include `pipeline` in filename. `find` works recursively so there is no need for `-R` flag to `grep`. Then it executes `grep -l pipeline` and `{}` denotes arguments passed by `find`. They get inserted one by one so `grep` runs on each file. `-l` denotes that you want filenames of matches only and `\` signals `-exec` that this is the end of command it should execute.

For example, your tree structure is

```
.
|--pipeline.txt
|--whatpipe.txt
|--anotherdir
   |--pipeline1.txt
   |--xyz.txt
   |--anotherdir1
      |--abapipeline.txt
```

and file contents are

```
**./pipeline.txt**
vnsdkvmvd
mvckdslm

**./whatpipe.txt**
vnsdkvmXYZvd
mvckdslm

**./anotherdir/pipeline1.txt**
vnsdkvmXYZvd
mvckdslm

**./anotherdir/xyz.txt**
vnsdkvmvd
mvckdslm

**./anotherdir/anotherdir1/abapipeline.txt**
vnsdkvmXYZvd
mvckdslm
```

The output would then be

```
$ find . -name "*pipeline*" -exec grep -l XYZ {} \;
anotherdir/pipeline1.txt
anotherdir/anotherdir1/abapipeline.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `grep -R` ignores standard input.  Thus, for this command, the output of `find` is ignored.  `grep -R` performs its own independent search for files of any name:

```
find . -name "*pipeline*" | grep -R 'pipeline'
```

The solution is to remove `find` and use grep's `include` option:

```
grep -R --include='*pipeline*' pipeline
```

#### Example

Consider a directory with these files:

```
$ find . -type f
./social/pipeline.py
./social/match_but_wrong_name.py
./not_a_match
```

Our command finds only the desired file:

```
$ grep -R --include='*pipeline*' pipeline
social/pipeline.py:    print ("at pipeline *******", details, uid, social, kwargs, response)
```

The option `--include='*pipeline*'` tells grep to only search for files whose names contain the string `pipeline`.

#### Documentation

From `man grep`:

> --include=GLOB
>                Search only files whose base name matches GLOB (using  wildcard matching as described under --exclude).